# Should a class that contains an injected IHttpClientFactory be Scoped, Singleton or Transient when the class itself is registered in DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using the recommended `IHttpClientFactory` via DI in ASP.NET Core. In some cases where I want to use named clients, I do not want to inject `IHttpClientFactory` directly into my controller classes. Instead, I want to use a wrapper class, say `IHttpClientHelperService`/`HttpClientHelperService`, that contains an injected `IHttpClientFactory` instance along with some helper methods for convenience.

So then I need to register `IHttpClientHelperService`/`HttpClientHelperService` in Startup.cs so that I can inject instances of them into calling classes that need them.

My question is, should this be registered via `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped`, or `AddTransient`? I'm thinking since `IHttpClientFactory` is a "factory" that manages `HttpClient`, I should register my wrapper class as singleton so that only one factory instance is created for the application. I'm just not sure if this will cause any issues.

Your advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you *really* need to use `IHttpClientFactory` directly in the first place? In most cases, having a service that requests a `HttpClient` through constructor injection and that is registered through `services.AddHttpClient` is enough (and better)

Comment: a factory is usually a singleton. your wrapper class however may be different depending on the detailed implementation. If it's just a pure wrapper without additional unrelated logics to the IHttpClientFactor, you can use it as a singleton as well. The safe way is always use it as a scoped service, the trade-off is a bit of extra object instantiation as well as memory, especially it's fine when the singleton does not maintain any persistent in-memory data.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know it's possible to inject `HttpClient` via typed client registration. But sometimes my logic needs to choose a specific client at runtime. This does not work well with constructor typed client injection. Instead a `IHttpClientFactory` instance will allow me to call `_httpClientFactory.CreateClient(namedClient)` to obtain any named client from the factory.